# Get the determinant of a block matrix given the submatrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, block-matrices

I have a matrix $M$ that is equal to: 
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}$

It's easy to compute $|M| = -2$, but then given matrix:

$ N = \begin{bmatrix}
M & 0 \\
0 & M \\
\end{bmatrix}$

What is $|N|$? My textbook and multiple sources say it's $ |N| = -1$. But I couldn't find any explanation as to why. Wikipedia's Determinants page says it's $det(N) = det(M)det(M)$ which is 4. That makes sense to me. Why it says -1 in the solutions manual does not. I've even tried expanding the matrix out into a 6x6 matrix and getting the determinant of that (used calculator to make sure), but it's still 4.

$ det(N) = |\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}| = 4?$

Comment: You are completely right, $\det(N)=(-2)^2=4$. Did you check the matrix $M$ for typos?

Comment: Yes. Very carefully. Thank you for reaffirming my sanity

Comment: Moreover, $|N|=-1$ can’t be correct since that would mean that $|M|$ is imaginary.